# open new activity then fragment goes to root fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am opening activity like whatsapp or camera from fragment but when i am going back from current activity then it goes to root fragment instead of recent fragment. So i need to use another fragment activity for recent fragment or any other solution is there ? I have searched a lot but till now did not get appropriate solution.

```
    private void galleryIntent()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
        }

        private void cameraIntent()
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            getActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
                    onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
                else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
                    onCaptureImageResult(data);
            }
        }

 private void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data) {
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
        byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();

//        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "dir/savings.csv");
//        if (!destination.exists()) {
//            destination.mkdirs();
//            destination.createNewFile();
//        }
//
//        File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"Wish-A-Mitr"+File.separator,
//                System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");


        File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File destination = new File(path, System.currentTimeMillis() +".jpg");


        FileOutputStream fo;
        try {
           if(path.exists())
           {
               path.mkdirs();
               destination.createNewFile();
           }

            fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
            fo.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        roundedImageView.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), thumbnail);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
        finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private void onSelectFromGalleryResult(Intent data) {

        Bitmap bm=null;
        if (data != null) {
            try {
                bm = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getActivity().getContentResolver(), data.getData());
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);
                byteArray = bytes.toByteArray();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        roundedImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE URI FROM THE BITMAP
        Uri tempUri = getImageUri(getContext(), bm);

        // CALL THIS METHOD TO GET THE ACTUAL PATH
         finalFile = new File(getRealPathFromURI(tempUri));

    }

    public Uri getImageUri(Context inContext, Bitmap inImage) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        inImage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(inContext.getContentResolver(), inImage, "imageFile", null);
        return Uri.parse(path);
    }

    public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
```

Comment: please edit your question and add code of onSelectFromGalleryResult(data) and onCaptureImageResult(data)

Comment: I have added the code.